# Check if all elements are unique with nonhashable list

Tags: python, list

New to Python here. I've figured out that it's rather trivial to check if a list has all unique elements using

```
  if len(lst) > len(set(lst))
```

But how would I deal with a case like this?

```
all_different([[],[],[],[]]) #False
```

I can't use the set() function in this example. I understand how I might do this (rather inefficiently) with nested for loops in Java. But not sure how I could implement this in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hash lists as they're mutable, but you can convert them to tuples, and hash them instead. Like so: `set(tuple(elem) for elem in lst)`

Your comparison would then become:

```
myset = set(tuple(elem) for elem in lst)
if len(lst) > len(myset)
```

Comment: you should flatten `lst` in the `if`

Comment: @Marcos Flattening isn't appropriate, but if the list isn't flat then we need to process it recursively to tuplify inner lists.

Comment: The second example in the post led me to think that nested lists were a possibility (in fact, that they where the case troubling the OP).